# Issue with adding keyboard shortcut to a CLI application in Ubuntu (20.04) gnome

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys

I'm trying to add keybindings so I can launch CLI-based applications easier. Take [Ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger) for example. When I try to set the keyboard shortcut command field in settings to `ranger` it just doesn't work. I tried to google it and only found [this Ubuntu wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings), which doesn't help much.

I get the feeling that I completely lack some knowledge on how console-based applications are launched, because I also couldn't set ranger as default file manager. Is the problem related to them being shellscripts and not compiled code/binaries?

Could you help me understand the subject, or maybe help me with a few good sources?

Comment: What is ranger? What Ubuntu wiki page did you find?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts launch processes in a non-interactive shell. Graphical programs create windows, so soon you get to interact with them through the windows. Terminal programs, however, run somewhere inside your system without connection to standard in (keyboard) and standard out (screen), so you cannot interact with them.

To launch a terminal program from a keyboard shortcut in a way you can interact with it, you need to launch it in a terminal emulator. Using `gnome-terminal`, entering the following keyboard shortcut command will work:

```
gnome-terminal -- ranger
```

Whenever you quit `ranger`, `gnome-terminal` will also be closed.

Changing a default file manager unfortunately [is not easy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager). Still, you can create a launcher for`ranger` to easily launch it also through the menu system.

To that aim, create a `.desktop` launcher in `~/.local/share/applications` (.local is a hidden folder in your home directory `~`;  change this to `/usr/local/share/applications` if you want this to work for all users on the system) with name for example `ranger.desktop` and following text

[Desktop Entry]
Exec=ranger %F
Terminal=true
Name=Ranger
Comment=Console based file manager
Type=Application
[/code]

This will automatically cause an icon to be created, which will appear in the application menu of the desktop. If you want a specific icon instead of a generic icon, then place a graphics file for the icon (e.g ranger.png, or ranger.svg) in `~/.local/share/icons`, and add the line `Icon=ranger` to the desktop launcher.

To change the mimetype so file links automatically will open with that launcher, use the `xdg-mime` command. First check the current association:

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

and take note of the output in case you want to revert the change, effectuated by the following command:

```
xdg-mime default ranger.desktop inode/directory
```

This way, a command like `xdg-open /path/to/folder` will open the folder in ranger in a new terminal window instead of in the standard file manager of the desktop.

A nice and brief resource on how the desktop works is found here: [https://readthedocs.org/projects/penguin-carpentry/downloads/pdf/latest/`](https://readthedocs.org/projects/penguin-carpentry/downloads/pdf/latest/%60)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the expansive answer, it helps a lot!